# Please check a newbie's script

Tags: html

Please check my script below.

Im trying to add some color to some of the text... this is what i have managed to work out thus far.. is it correct?

```
<center> You will be redirected to the number one proven training system in <span style="color:blue;font-weight:bold"> <span id="countdowntimer">12 </span> Seconds </span> </center>

<script type="text/javascript">
var timeleft = 12;
var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
timeleft--;
document.getElementById("countdowntimer").textContent = timeleft;
if(timeleft <= 0)
    clearInterval(downloadTimer);
},1000);
```

Comment: Does it achieve the result you expected? That is how you determine if it's correct.

Comment: Does the code you've posted *add some color to some of the text*? We can't see the page where this out of context script is being used, so you're the only one that can decide if it's working or not.

Comment: it's a perfectly valid way of counting down the seconds. However, where you change the color is not really visible

Comment: Please refrain from chatty titles that don't tell us anything. This question was likely downvoted because the title "please help a newbie" won't assist anyone in the future in working out what the question is about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the text of the countdown is blue if that is what you mean. Ifyou want to change the color when the timer runs out try something like...

```
if(timeleft <= 0)
clearInterval(downloadTimer);
document.getElementById("countdowntimer").style = "color:red";
```

You might find tools like https://jsfiddle.net/vnjgngo1/ helpful in the future. In this fiddle you can paste your code and html in two separate blocks.

Comment: thank you very much